# Why doesn't "He used to take me to the first game when I was only 6" work?

Tags: word-choice, past-tense, used-to

I took placement test and here is one question I am curious about.

> 1. He____ me to the first game when I was only 6.

I thought the answer was

> a) Used to take

but it says

> c) took

Comment: "Used to" suggests it was a habitual action.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: The question you post in the title is not the question you give underneath it.

Comment: looks the same to me, but since PiuPiu hasn't been on the site in 3 years and never made an account on [ell.se] I think the chance of getting a reply is close to zero.

Answer (score 3):

"Used to take" implies that he did it repeatedly but if it's referring to a specific incident (the first game) then it only have happened once.

Comment: *Used to X* can't be used if X only happened once.